# Testing using Truffle unbox: Assert.equal error

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I ran the pet shop project. It uses "truffle unbox". The petshop project at:
[Petshop project using Assert.equal without any error](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop)

is able to execute Assert.equal command but when I am using Assert.equal, I am getting error. I am first deploying the pet-shop project in my project folder using "truffle unbox petshop". It creates the files but then I modified the files as follows.
My files are (got from [Michalzalecki](https://michalzalecki.com/ethereum-test-driven-introduction-to-solidity/)):

```
//Funding.sol

pragma solidity 0.5.16;
contract Funding {
   address public owner;
   constructor() public {
      owner = msg.sender;
   }
}

//2_deploy_contracts.js
var Funding= artifacts.require("Funding");
module.exports = function(deployer){
   deployer.deploy(Funding);
};
```

//TestFunding.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Funding.sol";

contract  TestFunding{

  function testSettingAnOwnerDuringCreation() public {
    Funding funding = new Funding();
    Assert.equal(funding.owner, address(this), "An owner is different than a deployer");
  }
}
```

I am getting following error when I am compiling my code using "truffle test":

> $ truffle test You can improve web3's peformance when running Node.js
> versions older than 10.5.0 by installing the (deprecated) scrypt
> package in your project Using network 'development'.
>
> Compiling your contracts...
> ===========================
>
> > Compiling ./test/TestFunding.sol
>
> /test/TestFunding.sol:10:5:
> TypeError: Member "equal" not found or not visible after
> argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert).
> Assert.equal(funding.owner, address(this), "An owner is different than a deployer");
> ^----------^
>
> Compilation failed. See above. Truffle v5.1.33 (core: 5.1.33) Node
> v8.10.0

Somebody please guide me how can I modify the pet-shop project to create a new project for testing so that it can use Assert.equal(...)command.

I am getting the same error after changing the **Assert to 'assert'**:

$ truffle test

> You can improve web3's peformance when running Node.js versions older
> than 10.5.0 by installing the (deprecated) scrypt package in your
> project Using network 'development'.
>
> Compiling your contracts...
> ===========================
>
> > Compiling ./test/TestFunding.sol
>
> /test/TestFunding.sol:10:5:
> TypeError: Member "equal" not found or not visible after
> argument-dependent lookup in function (bool) pure.
> assert.equal(funding.owner, address(this), "An owner is different than a deployer");
> ^----------^
>
> Compilation failed. See above. Truffle v5.1.33 (core: 5.1.33) Node
> v8.10.0

Zulfi.

Comment: what does the function.owner() function return? Can you show us the whole contract?

Comment: and you need to use adress(this) not this only to get back the contract’s address

Comment: I have corrected 'owner', its a state variable. I have provided the link for original code which mistakenly shows parenthesis with 'owner'. Code is complete.

Comment: Still the problem persists and I am getting error with "Assert.equal(...)".